# LDIF (LDAP) attributes list

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldif

I've been looking on the web but so far... not luck!

Where can I find a list of all the LDIF attributes and corresponding values (e.g., "objectClass" may have "top", "person", ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the [RFC - https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2798.txt](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2798.txt) for the `iNetOrgPerson` object class.  `iNetOrgPerson` extends `organizationalPerson` which extends `person`. This is probably the most common way to represent information about people in directory servers.

There are other object classes which in turn define sets of allowed attributes. Some are open standards and some are proprietary to specific directory server or applications implemented on directory servers. You can also define your own.

Answer (score 2):

While Dave's answer is definitely the correct official reference, I find this list of [Commonly Used LDAP Attributes](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ape/#attributes) more helpful, especially if you are not yet too deep into it.